# 64-bit Global Variable Memory Issue

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller, flash-memory

In the beginning I would like to mention that this issue occurs for one application, and it does not occur for another application with the same configuration and accessing the same source code.
In my application, I needed to extend a read/write global variable from 32 bits to 64 bits using MPC5644A.

```c
    unsigned long long extendedVar1 = 0x0ULL;
    void function (unsigned long long var2 )
    {
        extendedVar1 |= var2;
    }
```

The program builds every time, but it  fails to be flashed to the ecu for an application this happened all the time, and for another application with the same environment configs and accessing the same extended variable from the same source file this issue doesn't occur,the resulting binary file is not that big, but still this problem occurs when it's extended to 64 bits for some application using the same MCU.

I thought it's a memory allocation issue so I tried an absolute addressing for this variable at the address 0x6FF88 and everything went well.

used gcc version:gcc-8.1.0
used IDE: visual studio 2005

Any contribution to this question would be very helpful for me.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. It is probably an UB which manifests itself this way.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by UB?

Comment: What does this have to do with [x86-64]?  MPC5644A isn't an x86-64 CPU.  This is missing a ton of details, like what the total size of your compiled binary is when the variable is 32-bit vs. 64-bit.  Is MPC5644A a 32-bit microcontroller, so 64-bit operations take multiple instructions everywhere you use the variable?

Comment: UB stands for "undefined behaviour". (http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). Unlikely that's the problem, since you're saying it compiled but you couldn't even flash the code to your test board, I think?  Unless compile-time-visible UB led to a much bigger executable for some reason.  Normally UB leads to unpredictable behaviour at run time.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the generated .bin/.elf files remain the same size, 513 KB for the binary file and 747 KB for the .elf file. The size does not change with the declaration  unsigned long long extendedVar1 = 0x0ULL; or  unsigned int extendedVar1 = 0x0U;